# What are the identity conditions for " a truth"

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics, reference-request, ontology, truth

Here I'm not talking about "truth" in general ( as when one says " truth is correspondence between thought and reality") but about  truth considered as a particular truth, as when one says  " this truth has been discovered by Galileo".

Under which conditions can one say that two truths are one and the same truth?

What individuates "a truth" ?

A famous philosopher once said " no entity without identity". That's why the question seems important to me.

What is the "ontological status" of " a truth"? ( Assuming, maybe erroneously , that this use of the word " truth" is correct.)

Here of course I'm thinking of the sense /denotation  distinction.

But there might be other aspects of the question.

Let me know what are your reflexions on this question ( or, maybe, which references could be indicated on this topic).

Comment: "Truth" is a polysemic term, so there are no identity conditions for "the truth" or "a truth" as such. If you are looking for identity conditions with respect to historical discoveries, this is actually quite controversial, and often involves a great deal of stretching and anachronism (as in saying that Galileo discovered the "principle of relativity"), but not really that different from the classical [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus). [Causal theory of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_theory_of_reference) is an attempt to conceptualize such things

Comment: There is no object called "a truth": there are true statments and false one.

Comment: Quine touches a little on these points in his book "Philosophy of Logic" Tarski says the grass is green only if the grass is green. Then T. But is it really green? Phililosophy of Logic by Quine, 
Collège de France (1969: Philosophy of Logic course in French; 1979, in French) and in an English language book.

Comment: Conférence à l’Université d’Aix-en-Provence, 1979.  Quine may have delivered the lecture in Aix sponsored by CDF. http://poincare.univ-lorraine.fr/fr/cours-au-college-de-france-et-conferences  Here is the English language book. https://www.amazon.com/Philosophy-Logic-Willard-Orman-Quine/dp/0674665635#aw-udpv3-customer-reviews_feature_div

Comment: @Gordon. Thanks for these links and references.

Comment: UW. It was easy. Here is Quine's log of travels and you can scroll down to France. http://www.wvquine.org/wvq-lecture-travel.html